# Determine the largest possible number of prime numbers between any 100 consecutive natural numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers

Determine the largest possible number of prime numbers between any 100 consecutive natural numbers. I have tried with prime number theorem, but can someone solve it without using that? I'm interested to so how would you solve that in that particular way, because I have no idea.

Comment: I found that the largest number is 26, from 2 to 101, I just don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Use Erathostenes sieve with the first 5 primes in the interval $[n; n+99]$ and you will get as many primes as in $[2; 101]$. You cannot get more than those. The largest possible number of primes is $\pi(101) = 26$.

Comment: @Crostul Why are you giving them a solution in a comment rather than in an answer post?

Comment: @Loki Yes; out of $100$ consecutive numbers exactly $50$ will be divisible by $2$, at least $33$ of them will be divisible by $3$, exactly $20$ are divisible by $5$, etcetera. This already leaves at msot $26$ primes if $2$, $3$ and $5$ are not in the interval.